# How can I find speed of a feature point (certain pixel) in dense optical flow for temporal window of 15 frames?

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

I want to track every pixel as feature point for temporal window of 15 frames using Farneback Dense optical flow. Using flow=cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next,None,0.5,3,15,3,5,1.2,0) , it shows dx and dy of every pixel in previous frame. Here I want to track certain feature  point pixel over 15 frames and find the speed of that feature point.

How can speed can be estimated by dense optical flow of a feature point with a sequence of spatial locations over time with trajectory legth L ?

Comment: If you plan to track a feature over time, maybe sparse optical flow is better (at least faster), but you can always track a pixel movement using this dx and dy, just get the length of this vector and add it all and divide by time and you get the speed (if you want it with direction then you need to work it a little more). The problem is, that this will be discretized in every step, and you will loose accuracy of the feature tracking, therefore I think with a sparse method tracking a feature is more accurate

Comment: As I read in one paper tracking by dense trajectories can detect fast / irregular motions than sparse optical flow. As  I am working in crowd behavior detection in video, I need to detect fast motion.  I need to remove static points in video and find motion speed / direction of that pixel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have dx and dy. With this information you can always have the velocity of such pixel if you know the time `t`.

```
vx =  dx / t
vy =  dy / t
```

dx and dy can be negative, therefore it will keep kind of the orientation... remember that the origin is the top left corner and points right and down.

This way you can have the speed of each pixel per frame per dimension. You can always do a follow up of the pixel and calculate its trajectory **length** and divide it over time, you can say is the average speed of the pixel in a way.

For that you calculate the length of each point in the trajectory:

```
length =  sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
```

and add them following the pixel, by that i mean something like:

```
totalLength = length(prev1[y,x]) + length(prev2[y+prev1[y,x][1], prev2[x+prev1[y,x]][0]]) ....
```

and then divide totalLength with the time.

If you want the speed of the total displacement, by that I mean the speed from the initial point till the end point (could be 0 if the pixel go back and forth) then just track the pixel by adding the displacements and then calculate the speed.

```
disp = (x,y) + prev1[y,x] + prev2[y,x] ...
speed = disp / t
```

I hope this helps you, if not jsut leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you . As i understand from above , I could track the feature point at suppose (0,0) position moved to  (32,23) pixel .position. I will use Median filtering tracking . How can static feature feature points be removed from dense trajectories ? Is that by checking whetehr dispalcement is above threshold or not?

Comment: if the displacement is below, lets say 3 pixels, then it is not moving. But remember to use length or other thing. I do not remember how OpenCV handles pixels that disappear (that move out of the picture), so you should be careful of that as well